# local apache server shows foreign ip addresses

Tags: apache, xampp, access-log

the thing that bothers me is that I've set up a local apache server with xampp and in the access log I see foreign IP addresses with irrelevant for my server get requests and I don't know why or how they try to access my server. I'd be really happy if someone helps me out.

Comment: You are the admin of the system, you have access to the logs and the configuration, you also have visibility of the network it sits in. You've provided no details of any of these. We can't help.

Comment: Sorry. I'm a newbie in that area. The server is at localhost of my machine and its used by development only by me. I'm in home network alone.